# How to Troubleshoot 'Cannot Connect to Proxy' Error - AWS S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

New to AWS and AWS CLI, I have installed and configured the AWS CLI, and I am simply trying to list the buckets in S3, but I am behind a proxy.

How do I troubleshoot and resolve and the following error?

C:\Users\MyUserName\Desktop >aws s3 ls

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', error(10060, 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond')))
```

The only troubleshooting step I have attempted is to Set the HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY variables to my IP on port 80.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key to using the AWS CLI behind a proxy is to configure two environment variables.

The IP address is the address of your proxy server, which is probably not your local IP. Consult with your network administrator to get the correct IP address and basic authentication parameters.

Chrome, IE, etc. support proxy servers, so you may already have these parameters setup in your browser. For Chrome go to `settings` and search for `Open proxy settings`. Similar technique for other browsers.

For Windows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://a.b.c.d:n
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://w.x.y.z:m
```

Or for basic authentication:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@a.b.c.d:n
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@w.x.y.z:m
```

For Linux, macOS, or Unix:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://a.b.c.d:n
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://w.x.y.z:m
```

Or for basic authentication:

```
export HTTP_PROXY=http://username:password@a.b.c.d:n
export HTTPS_PROXY=http://username:password@w.x.y.z:m
```

[Using an HTTP Proxy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-http-proxy.html)